# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, middleware

I am trying to redirect the admin to dashboard page by the following codes but when I enter `/dashboard`, the browser displays a `NotFoundHttpException` error page. 
**Middleware (AdminCheck.php) :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminCheck
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->authenticate();

        if ($user->role !== 'admin')
        {
            return redirect(route('login'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php (App\Http\Kernel.php) :**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'adminCheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminCheck::class,
    ];
```

**Route (App\routes\web.php) :**

```
Route::get('dashboard', function (){
    // 
})->middleware('auth', 'adminCheck');
```

**dashboard.php :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class dashboard extends Controller
{
    public function index () 
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

When I enter `http://localhost:8000/dashboard` there is an error page displayed that says :

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

I seem so dumb by not being able to fix it. Would you help me find out where my problem is? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I changed **/dashboard** to **dashbpard** and now the error has chenged to be: `InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [dashboard] not defined.` !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it comes from your controller name. Laravel follows the PSR-4 standard for autoloading classes, [see doc here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), your class name should start by an uppercase :

> \NamespaceName{\SubNamespaceNames*}\ClassName

Try to rename your dashboard.php into Dashboard.php, remake a `php composer dumpautoload` to see ? This route should work after that :

`Route::get('dashboard', 'Dashboard@index')->middleware('auth', 'adminCheck');`

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you got problem like this you haven't define your path url in route. please add this your route :

```
Route::resource('dashboard','YourController');
```

and some tips if you find the error and have no idea what's going on, you can go to `laravel.log` file for more detail about your error, you can find it here : `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 1):

Make your route to use `index` method of `dashboard` class for /dashboard usl

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'adminCheck']], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', dashboard::class . '@index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a view called `dashboard.blade.php` in your `resources/view` folder?


This error occurs when you do not have a blade template. Or sometimes, you may had made a mistake when you name it. So it may have `dashbord.blade.php` not `dashboard.blade.php`

Comment: did you do `view clear` and `route clear` for your project? It may help you.